# Facebook User and App Have Right Permissions, but Open Graph Refuses To Post a "Like" to Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Here's the scenario:

I have been developing a Facebook app for a few weeks, and when I tested it, my default "like" action worked perfectly fine. In testing, without submitting the action for approval yet, I never had any major problems. I could "like" stuff just fine and it would show up in my activity log.

I submitted this action to be approved on Saturday. This morning, the action was effectively approved, so I shouldn't have any any problems, right? Well, when I try to run the action once again, I get this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3506) The action type likes:Like does not exist or is not approved, so app 145634995501895 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User 690377433 is not one of those roles.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3506
  }
}
```

Doesn't matter if I run my action via my iOS app or via the Graph API Explorer, the result is always the same. A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. My action exist and it has been approved. I am absolutely certain I am looking at the right action because my app only has one, and in the Open Graph section of my app config, the action has the green "approved" circle.
2. User 690377433 is actually the administrator of the Facebook app.

So both reasons my publication should fail should never happen, given that my action exists and is approved and given that the user is the administrator of the app.

What could go wrong? This literally started happening after my action was approved by Facebook. Prior to this I have never seen this message in all the past months I have been working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a few hours with the iOS app, I found that the Graph API Explorer and the iPhone app were giving completely different errors.

I have fixed an error, but the iOS error said something in the lines of "Action already associated with user ID". Played a bit with my URLs and everything seems to be working fine.